# C best practice to allocate an array inside the if statement

Tags: c

Recently I get interested in CUDA and it seems much natural to convert C programs into CUDA than Fortran to CUDA (Apart from the main question in this post, is this really true?).

So I am learning C now, and bit surprised that the if statements in C behaves in a quite different way than the Fortran.

For example, the following code works just as expected in Fortran

```
program test
real(kind=selected_real_kind(15)),  allocatable :: arr_double(:)
integer                          ,  allocatable :: arr_int(:)
logical                                         :: flag_int, flag_double

flag_int    = .false.
flag_double = .true.

if (flag_int) then
  allocate(arr_int(10))
  arr_int = 1
  print *, arr_int
else if (flag_double) then
  allocate(arr_double(10))
  arr_double = 1.
  print *, arr_double
end if

if (flag_int) then
  deallocate(arr_int)
else if (flag_double) then
  deallocate(arr_double)
end if

end program
```

and its output is like following - again, it is as expected.

```
  1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000 
  1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000 
  1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000        1.00000000000000 
  1.00000000000000
```

However, its C counterpart does not work and gives error even in the compile-time (icc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  size_t dim1;
  bool   flag_int, flag_double;

  flag_int    = false;
  flag_double = true;

  if (flag_int) {
    int (*arr1d) = calloc(dim1, sizeof(*arr1d));
  }else if(flag_double) {
    double (*arr1d) = calloc(dim1, sizeof(*arr1d));
  }

  free(arr1d);

}
```

It seems that the compile fails because in C the code lines under if () {...} is only local inside the {...}.

Then, if I want to allocate different type of array (i.e. int or double) depending on some if statement, then what would be the best practice to do this?

ps. I want to note that I encountered this problem just playing with the C, and not going to use this kind of ugly code in my actual work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much Fortran, but I see that in your Fortran code you have mentioned both `arr_double` and `arr_int` up at the top, right under `program test`. I assume this makes those identifiers available for the later `allocate` and `deallocate` statements.

You can do the same sort of declaration in C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  size_t dim1 = 10;
  double *arr_double = NULL;
  int *arr_int = NULL;
  bool   flag_int, flag_double;

  flag_int    = false;
  flag_double = true;

  if (flag_int) {
    arr_int = calloc(dim1, sizeof *arr_int);
  } else if (flag_double) {
    arr_double = calloc(dim1, sizeof *arr_double);
  }

  free(arr_int);
  free(arr_double);
}
```

Note that I don't have to check the flags before deallocating with `free`, because I initialized both `arr_int` and `arr_double` to null pointers, and `free` is required to do nothing when given a null pointer.

As for “what would be the best practice to do this?”, your example is so much a toy program that I don't think there's much useful advice to give.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense. One more question then - how can I do the similar with 3D array?
I naively expected

int (*arr3d_int)[][]=NULL; ...; arr3d[dim2][dim3] = calloc(dim1,sizeof(*arr3d_int));

will do the work but it didn't. Since most posts say that I should avoid using multiple pointer (***ptr stuff) in dynamic allocation and recommends int(*arr3d_int)[dim2][dim3] = calloc(...) kind of allocation, I want to stick with this

Comment: You must declare a *pointer-to-2d-array*. That would be `int (*arr3d)[dim2][dim3] = NULL;` then allocate with `malloc (dim1 * sizeof *arr3d)`, or use `calloc()`. You cannot declare `int (*arr3d)[][]` -- which is an *incomplete type*. (`sizeof *arr3d` cannot be determined by the compiler)  `dim1`, `dim2` must be constants, e.g. `#define dim1 50` and `#define dim2 dim1` (or whatever you need) Also, always check the return from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` to ensure the allocation succeeded.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin dim1 and dim2 don't have to be constants since C99

Comment: @tstanisl C99 introduced the VLA, C11 made compiler support for VLAs optional. For maximum portability, you would use constants, if not needed, then VLAs will suffice.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Note that C23 **will** make VLA types mandatory again.

Comment: @tstanisl - that's good information -- considering I'm still digesting C18...